# How to measure the max available online user amount per second?

Tags: asp.net

How to measure the max available online user amount per second for a web app using asp.net?

Is there any tool to measure that?

I am looking for load testing, to find out how many users my app can handle.

Is there any recommended load testing tool?

Comment: Mike, there are not users per second, you need to think some other way to count your users, maybe active sessions (just count your sessions), maybe users in the last 20 minute, maybe total request be minute. Think something else, or describe what you need that for...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the ASP.NET counters in Windows Performance Monitor?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that. But how can it tell me the most available online user number per second for my web app?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you looking for load testing, to find out how many users your app can handle? In that case you will have to use specific load testing tools.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for load testing, to find out how many users my app can handle. Is there any recommended load testing tool?